# Django app copied to new location is still accessing old files, because it is using the wrong settings.py

Tags: django

Django version 1.4, using Supervisor, NGINX, gunicorn, and postgresql 8.4. The project where an app was located has been moved to a different server which also has the domain now. I had another project hosted on this same server, and I want to move my app over to that project with all database data intact.

I moved the app files (models.py, views.py, etc.) to a folder in the destination project, moved the templates to corresponding folders, added the app to the destination project's settings.py, and ran manage.py syncdb. Using PGAdmin's backup and restore I moved all of the data over. After updating some relative references in the python files I was able to access all of the database data (which seems entirely intact) in the Django admin site.

Now the problem: the new urls seem to work fine, but it is using the old project's .py files and all templates. I even commented out the app in the settings files of both new and old projects and all it did was hide the admin site from me.

To identify the problem I inserted a typo into the old project views.py, and got it to throw a traceback, which let me see that it was using the old project's settings.py instead of the new one. How do I make the app switch to the new project settings.py? How is it even finding the old one?

Comment: Have you restarted gunicorn?

Comment: I restarted everything I could think of: gunicorn, supervisor, nginx. I deleted all of the .pyc files in the application directory and in the project directory, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize after the fact that this question probably belongs on Server Fault instead of Stackoverflow. I did figure this out, though, and posted the answer on SF:

https://serverfault.com/a/722742/311615